# generic form of std::istream::read?

Tags: c++, generics, c++11, iostream

I'd love it if there was some kind of generic version of `std::istream::read`, so I could do this:

```c
ClassA func( std::istream& is ) {
  ClassA a;
  is.read(a);
  return a;
}
```

or

```c
ClassA func( std::istream& is ) {
  return is.read<ClassA>();
}
```

or maybe even:

```c
ClassA::ClassA( std::istream& is ) {
  is.read(data_member);
}
```

But I always have to supplement my own generic definitions like so:

```c
template< class T >
void load( T& v, std::istream& is ) {
  is.read((char*)&v, sizeof(v));
};

template< class T >
T load( std::istream& is ) {
  T v;
  is.read((char*)&v, sizeof(v));
  return v;
};
```

In doing this, I have to provide the stream as a parameter when it seems like maybe it should be a method on a stream object.

```c
load(a.data_member, is);
// vs
is.read(a.data_member);
```

I have a feeling that maybe I'm thinking about this problem incorrectly or that maybe it's stupid to even want this sort of thing.  I think it's silly that I have to tell `read()` about the size of the read when the compiler can infer it generically.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Creating an object by setting a value to its internal data is an UB

Comment: I'm basically trying to use `std::istream::read` without having to pass in the size of the read or use any explicit casts.  One application as presented here is reading bytes from a stream to construct an object.

Comment: You should not use C-style casts (`(char*)&v`) but C++-style casts instead: `reinterpret_cast<char *>(&v)`.

Comment: @kbok why would `reinterpret_cast` would be better?  Since `std::istream::read` wants the base memory address, would `(char*)` not be appropriate? (my understanding of reinterpret_cast's purpose isn't really clear)

Comment: `(char*)` and `reinterpret_cast` do the same thing, but `reinterpret_cast` is clearer in that it raises a "danger" flag.

Comment: You're saying reinterpret_cast serves a semantic purpose that signifies that you're doing screwy and possibly non-portable things with pointers?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your `load` function, just remember that it only works with POD types, so you should add:

```
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<T>::value, "A must be a POD type.");
```

Also, remember to turn on exceptions on your streams, or you won't get any error reporting at all - which is probably why streams don't provide such a way of reading into structs in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand why.  I think I'm taking this in a direction where a class/struct can either have a constructor that accepts a stream from which it will conduct a memberwise loading from the stream or maybe a static method that default-constructs one and then does a memberwise load from the stream.  As an added bonus, these streams are sometimes in network-byte-order.

Comment: I'll let client code worry about whether or not they care about stream errors ;)  They can turn on exceptions and establish a try block before calling for a load.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to simply wrap the stream. Something along these lines (not tested):

```
class ObjectStream
{
  std::istream& _is;
  public:
  ObjectStream(std::istream& _is) : _is(is) {};
  template <class T>
  ObjectStream& operator>>(T& v) {
    _is.read((char*)&v, sizeof(T));
    return *this;
  }
}
```

When you open your stream, simply put it inside an `ObjectStream` and pass that around instead of your istream - now you're able to read an object simply by doing `stream >> obj`, similar to how istream overloads `>>`.

Of course, you can also just use a regular instance method if you prefer that.

Comment: `operator>>` has the unfortunate semantic implication that the character type and locale are relevant.

Comment: @IronSavior: Then call the method `read`, and you'll still be able to do `stream.read(obj)`. The main point is that wrapping lets you write your code so the stream appears to do the work, instead of sending it as a parameter every time.

Comment: I could call it `read`, but then I'm basically treating this non `std::istream`-derived object as if it were a `std::istream`.